# Relation between Bhrugu and Manu

Tags: manu

While reading history book, I found that Manu had 10 sons. Sharyati (son of Manu) also had one son and daughter named Anart and Sukanya respectively. Where Sukanya married with Chyavan Rushi.

Now, Here is a confusion. If Manu was the first human on earth then from where this Chyavan Rushi comes? I also read that Brahma also had 8 sons. So is there possibility that both generation (Manu's and Brahma's) are living on earth same time?

Answer (score 4):

Svayambhu Manu(1st Manu) was the son of lord Brahma.Sage Bhrigu is also a son of Lord Brahma.

According to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyavana) Sharyati was the son of Vaivasvata Manu(7th Manu).
And as you have mentioned;Sukanya was his daughter.

Chyavan rishi married Sukanya.

Chyavan rishi was the son of Sage Bhrigu.It is mentioned in [Adi parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01009.htm) of MahaBharata.

> "Sauti said, 'O Brahmana, Chyavana, the son of Bhrigu, begot a son in
> the womb of his wife Sukanya. And that son was the illustrious Pramati
> of resplendent energy. And Pramati begot in the womb of Ghritachi a
> son called Ruru. And Ruru begot on his wife Pramadvara a son called
> Sunaka. And I shall relate to you in detail, O Brahmana, the entire
> history of Ruru of abundant energy. O listen to it then in full!

So the relation would be that Bhrigu's son(Chyavan) married the Grand-Daughter of manu(VaiVasvata).